# How to create a customer, payment method, subscription all in one step in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Stripe has so many different methods it's kinda confusing which one to used. I have a credit card form for the user after he/she has selected the subscription they want to purchase. From this point, I want to create the customer, setup payment and subscription all in one step.

Do I do:

1. Create customer
2. Create payment method
3. Create subscription

OR

1. Create Intent
2. Create Session

Or does creating a session handle create customer, create payment method and create subscription all in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the hosted [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) solution, you would not collect payment details yourself. Stripe does that for you as part of the Checkout flow. You *can* create a customer ahead of time, but by default Checkout will create one for you.

Most likely using Checkout with `mode=subscription` to [start a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout) is going to be your most straightforward option. If you do use Checkout this way, you would not create any Subscriptions/Intents directly yourself. You can also use the [Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal) to manage changes to the subscriptions later.

You can also go with the [custom flow](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription) you described, creating the customer, attaching payment methods and starting a subscription, but this is more involved.